# Implementing a login system with Auto-desk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, login-system

I am new to autodesk forge and am tasked with creating a website with it. The website must include a login/authentication system and the forge viewer to allow for customers to view their systems. I have set up the forge app which allows users to view their models with NodeJS and deployed it to heroku. This is the link to the tutorial https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs
I am now trying to link that app/program with a simple login/authentication system but have been unsuccessful. Do I need to use a nodejs authentication system as I have used that for autodesk forge. Also, how would I go about hiding certain models from the viewer based on who is logged in. Any examples where someone used a login system with forge would help a lot, also any tips and any guidance would be very much appreciated as I am very new to web-design.
Cheers!

Update:
Thanks for all your help

I am now using the three legged authorization. I am wondering if it is possible if users can log into a specific autodesk account, where certain models are hidden based on which user is logged in.

I am trying to create a website for our customers where they can log in and view our models that we provide for them. They will only have access to the models through the app. However certain models must be hidden as one customer should only be able to view the models that apply to them, not all in the account. Is something like this possible. Thanks for the help. 
Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!!  There are many many ways that an authentication system could be built, so your question is incredibly broad.  It will be difficult to answer.  You should try to reword your question to get specific answers.  And also take a look at the guide for good questions, which may help you!  Cheers.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Using the forge 3 legged authentication already limits the models the user can see. If you use a 3 legged context as per [this tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) you might find you dont need any additional system. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you have followed uses a simplified, *two-legged authentication* where your application's users do not have to log in. The application authenticates itself to Forge.

If you'd like to include *three-legged authentication* where your users would log in with their Autodesk account and access their own data, I'd suggest that you follow the 2nd tutorial on the same site: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels. This one explains the 3-legged auth in detail.

Comment: Thank you Petr, I am now using three-legged authentication. However, I am wondering if it is possible for me to hide some models on my autodesk account (i.e a folder is password protected). The users of this site could only access models through one auto-desk account, and I do not want one user to be able to view all the models on the account. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, once your user signs in with their Autodesk credentials, *your application* will have access to their content but it doesn't mean that you have to show the user all their folders. You can filter the folder structure that Forge sends you in any way you want before sending it to the client browser.